# How do I automatically open a google sheet after creating a copy in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that when run it creates a copy and saves it on a specific folder in google drive. My intention is to save and open the sheet on a mother tab or window to allow the active user to edit it. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
function copy_and_save() {

//Get the activesheet the user is on
  var form_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var main_tab = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
//Destination for the copy that is created.
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXX');
 
//Get email of active user and date to be used in the naming of the copy.
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var date = (new Date()).toDateString();
  
//copy the file to destination folder and open the file

 var mine = DriveApp.getFileById(form_sheet.getId()).makeCopy(email + date,destFolder).getId();
   
   return mine;


//This is the part that I got lost
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService
            .createHtmlOutput('<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + mine + '/" target="_blank">' + mine + '</a>')
            .setWidth(350) //optional
            .setHeight(50); //optional
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Click to open sheet');
        }
```

Comment: You can't.  Just send the user the path and let them open it up.  If you open it up with script then there will be no user interface it will only open on the server.

Comment: `function getPathFromId(id) {
  try {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
    var pA = [];
    pA.push(file.getName());
    var folder = file.getParents();
    while (folder.hasNext()) {
      var f = folder.next();
      pA.push(f.getName());
      folder = f.getParents()
    }
    var r = pA.reverse().join(' / ');
  }
  catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
  return r;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. You just need to know the id of the new sheet:

```
  var id = "Spreadsheet ID";
  var html = "<script>window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ id +"');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Loading');
```